# R CRAN check: Package has no Sweave vignette sources and no VignetteBuilder field

Tags: r, cran, r-package

With the newest R dev version I get the following error message:

> Package has no Sweave vignette sources and no VignetteBuilder field.

If I would use knitr for building my vignette, I would now add
VignetteBuilder: knitr to my DESCRIPTION file.

But I am actually using Sweave.

Adding VignetteBuilder: Sweave does not work for me.

> Fehler in loadVignetteBuilder(pkgdir, TRUE) : 
>    Vignetten-Erzeuger 'Sweave' nicht gefunden

What should I write in the VignetteBuilder field, if I am using Sweave?
Maybe you could also tell me what is meant with:" Sweave vignette sources"

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I solved this one.

My mistake was writing:

> VignetteBuilder: Sweave

in the DESCRIPTION file of the package.

The correct solution would be:

> VignetteBuilder: utils

since Sweave is part of the utils package.

Additionally, I found out that it is also important to add utils also to the Suggests field

> Suggests: utils